# SQL: How To Select Earliest Date

Tags: sql

I have a date column & I am simply trying to know the earliest date. I use the command:

```
select Min(Install_date) From PocketGemsSchema.pocketgemstable2;
```

This returns 1-Dec-17

But the minimum date from my sample data is actually 1-Nov-17.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Hello @Yves, what database do you use? (Oracle, MySQL, Sql Server ..)

Comment: Extremely unlikely. What is the type of column of Install_date. The result your're would be consistent with a varchar column.

Comment: Please add schema to the question.

Comment: the datatype of  `Install_date` might  be string , convert to date

Comment: Never, ever store dates as character. Use proper date data type!

Comment: Comparing strings,  `1-Dec-17` < `1-Nov-17`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
If your Install_date contain datatype varchar than

```
SELECT MIN(CAST(Install_date AS DATE)) 
FROM PocketGemsSchema.pocketgemstable2

SELECT FORMAT(MIN(CAST(Install_dateAS DATE)), 'dd-MMM-yy ') 
FROM PocketGemsSchema.pocketgemstable2
```

If your Install_date contain datatype date or datetime than your query will work

Answer (score 0):

I think its the data type issue , you can try two approach

1. convert the field to datatime and your query should work
2. cast it on the run time like below

Mysql

`SELECT Min(Str_to_date(Install_date, '%m/%d/%Y')) 
    FROM   pocketgemsschema.pocketgemstable2;`

SQL server

`SELECT Min(Cast(Install_date as datetime)) 
    FROM   pocketgemsschema.pocketgemstable2;`

Answer (score 0):

I would change the column to a date or a datetime type and sort out any bugs that arise.